# How to disable dontaudit denials in SEAndroid

Tags: kernel, security, android, selinux

My application is working in permissive mode, but not in Enforcing mode for  SEAndroid. Here i cleared (allowed) all denials,so now there is no denial logs coming in my logcat logs.So it might be cause dontaudit rules to hide denials. For that how to disable **dontaudit** denials in SEAndroid....
Please Suggest me the command to disable dontaudit in SEAndroid.

Thanks,

Comment: How did you clear the denials?

Comment: Cleared denials by writing allow rules .. Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

`dontaudit` is an [avc rule](https://selinuxproject.org/page/AVCRules#dontaudit).

Steps to disable this rule are same as disabling `neverallow`, `allow`, or `auditallow` rules: it involves re-writing the SELinux policy.

- To do so you have to modify the `.te` files concerning your app's SEcontext in 2 directories in your aosp source:

  ```
  system/sepolicy/private/
  system/sepolicy/public/
  ```
- You then rebuild the `selinux_policy` module in `aosp` (via `make selinux_policy`)
- Then copy the 3 compiled files to your phone:

  ```
  cd  out/target/product/<the_name_of_your_build>/system/etc/selinux/
  adb push plat_sepolicy.cil plat_and_mapping_sepolicy.cil.sha256 plat_file_contexts /etc/selinux/
  ```

Reboot the phone and... voilà!